# How to create an internal mediawiki link for a html div element

Tags: html, hyperlink, mediawiki

A plea to all wiki gurus - can anyone help me create a link to another page in the same wiki when the wiki page is constructed in html?

Alittle background & context: I decided to get a bit arty in my mediawiki and made a simple landing page constructed using CSS and div elements to sit on a mediawiki page. After a little fettling, I managed to get the HTML rendered correctly and the page looks very nice! 
Now I wish to use the div elements (lets call them 'buttons') as links to other mediawiki pages within the same wiki. (the actual 'buttons' are made up of several elements wrapped in a containing div element)

The actual html for a 'button' looks like this:

```
<div class="cf-box"><div class="cf-box-title">Button Title</div><div class="cf-button-icon"></div><div class="cf-box-text">Description of the information the button links to</div></div>
```

Using HTML, this would be a simple process of wrapping the containing element (cf-box) in a link and all is good in the world. I assumed that you would be able to do something similar in mediawiki such as..

```
[[Some Page|<div class="container"><div class="button"><div class="text"></div></div></div>]]
```

but when I try this, the outer 'container' opening and closing div elements are stripped out and displayed on the page as text leaving the internal div elements orphaned rendering garbage on the page. The link does work though!

Thanks to anyone who takes a look!